# What does TAB do (no other things typed)

Tags: bash

Just push TAB, the terminal gives me this:

```
Display all 2637 possibilities? (y or n)
```

What indeed does the TAB do for me?

Answer (score 8):

It's trying to auto-complete the command for you, and since you've typed nothing it's offering to show you every possibility in your path (i.e. 2,637 executable commands). The more characters you type, the fewer possibilities you'll get (or it'll fully complete if there's only one).

Comment: Yeah, I understand TAS is trying to complete what I want to type. But what essentially does it mean in my senariao?

Comment: That there are 2,637 executable commands in your path. Enter 'y' and it'll display them all.